# CBB60 Motor Run Capacitor Wiring

Tags: wiring, lawn-mower, capacitor

I recently went out and bought a CBB60 motor run capacitor to replace the one that came with my lawnmower.

I just wanted to ask, how would I go about wiring the capacitor up. The capacitor that I got has four terminals, and I, obviously, only need to use two of them. I included a picture of a similar capacitor, I would assume that the two terminals that seem to be connected to each other are represent one terminal (positive or negative) and the other two represent the other terminal. Its AC capacitors so it doesn't really matter in which way it is wired, as far as I'm aware.

The last thing then is that my capacitor comes with a thread at the bottom, but because the form factor of the new capacitor is slightly taller than the form factor of my old one, it doesn't fit perfectly in the old one's location. Before making a custom case, I just wanted to find out, could that thread serve as a sort of grounding point for the capacitor? Because if so, I will have to make sure that that thread is connected to the housing using a conductor.

Thanks so much everyone.

[image: Four-terminal CBB60 Capacitor]

Comment: How about a picture of the capacitor you need to replace, still connected? And clear pictures of the labeling of both old and new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumptions.

- Its an AC capacitor, so there is no polarity
- It really only has two terminals, the have provided you with extra one for reach in case.
- A capacitor does not need grounding.  As long as teh two terminals are connected, it will work.  Just make sure that the two wires you are connecting now, were connected to different terminal on the capacitor before.

Comment: Thanks! I tested it and it worked perfectly.